# Fragging with no V4 support

Tags: android-fragments, mvvmcross

Is there a fragging assembly that has been compiled without V4 support? When getting Fragging via Nuget, I'm stuck with a project that depends on Support.V4, but I'm targeting API Level 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried FullFragging?

http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Droid.FullFragging/

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/406

Comment: Thanks, Stuart, I didn't know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue targeting API Level 14 with V4 Support assembly, you must convert your Fragments to V4.Fragements